# sunrise / sunset calculation returning later values

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I'm calculating the sunrise and sunset based on the user's geolocation. I'm using the Islamic praytime.js to do these calculations. However, I am getting values for sunrise and sunset much later than they actually are at the location of the device that I am testing on.

How can I get the proper or a more accurate sunrise and sunset?

The praytimes code: http://praytimes.org/code/v2/js/PrayTimes.js

My implementation:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
        lat = pos.coords.latitude;
        lon = pos.coords.longitude;
        alert(lat+" long: "+lon);
        var prayTimes = new PrayTimes();
        var times = prayTimes.getTimes(new Date(), [lat, lon], getTimezoneOffset()/100);
        sunrise = times.sunrise.split(':');
        sunset = times.sunset.split(':');
        alert("sunrise: "+sunrise[0]+" hours, "+sunrise[1]+" minutes");
        alert("sunset: "+sunset[0]+" hours, "+sunset[1]+" minutes");
}
```

I swear I was getting accurate values when I was not using a lat and long and just the timezone, but now it is requiring me to give lat / long arguments after I downloaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let PrayTimes.js calculate the time-zone. You are dividing the time-zone by 100, why?

Just let the script detect the time-zone based on the geolocation:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    $('#input').removeClass('night');
    lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    lon = pos.coords.longitude;
    var prayTimes = new PrayTimes();
    var times = prayTimes.getTimes(new Date(), [lat, lon]);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your question since you only mention sunrise and sunset, but in some cases, the code you posted here won't show correct results because of higher latitudes. See this [page](http://praytimes.org/calculation/#Higher_Latitudes). To fix that you need to add something like this: `prayTimes.adjust( {highLats: 'AngleBased'} )`. This [page](http://praytimes.org/wiki/Code_Manual) also mentions the other values you can use.

Comment: Thank you— I'll keep note of that